# Pullbacks and isomorphisms of the form $id \times_Z f$ in Set

Tags: category-theory, pullback

Let $X \xrightarrow{x} Z \xleftarrow{y} Y$ be a cospan of sets, and consider the pullback $X \times_Z Y$.

Given $f\colon Y \to Y'$, I would like to show that $\newcommand{\id}{\operatorname{id}}\id_X \times_Z f$ is an isomorphism if, and only if, $f$ is an isomorphism.

The *if*-direction is clear, but I'm struggling with $\implies$.

Specifically, I'm struggling with showing that $(\id \times_Z f)^{-1}$ is again of the form $\id \times_Z g$.

So let $\id_X \times_Z f$ be invertible. By the universal property of pullbacks, we have
\begin{align}
  \operatorname{Fun}(X \times_Z Y', X\times_Z Y) \cong
  \{ (\alpha, \beta) \mid x \circ \alpha = y \circ \beta \}
  \subset 
  \operatorname{Fun}(X \times_Z Y', X) \times
  \operatorname{Fun}(X \times_Z Y', Y)
  \ ,
\end{align}
and given some map $u$ on the LHS, the two maps on the RHS are determined by
\begin{align}
  \alpha = \pi_1 \circ u \quad \text{and} \quad \beta = \pi_2 \circ u \ ,
\end{align}
where $\pi_i$ are the projections.
So, for $u = (\id_X \times_Z f)^{-1}$, we are obviously forced to have $\alpha = \pi_1$, but of $\beta$ we only know that its some function $X \times_Z Y' \to Y$ satisfying $\beta \circ \id \times_B f = \pi_2$.

So I don't really see how/where the $X$-dependence of $\beta$ vanishes. Any help would be appreciated.

---

**Edit:** Let us also assume that $X \to Z$ is a surjection and that $Z$ is not empty.

Comment: It's false when $X$ is empty, so you won't get a purely categorical proof...

Comment: Hm, we could, however, still consider the category of non-empty sets over $Z$ (which I also want to be non-empty), right?

Comment: @JoMo Well, yes, nevertheless if there were a purely categorical proof, then it would apply to $Set$ with empty set as well, but as Arnaud pointed out, it's false there.

Comment: @Berci Sorry if I'm being dense, but why would it apply to $Set$ as well? $Set$ is very different from $Set/Z$, no?

Comment: If you could finish off your proof (presumably by explicitly obtaining the inverse of $f$ in terms of the given data), then this construction would apply to *any* category with pullbacks, in particular to $Set$.